# how to ignore and skip a Python sftp error

Tags: python, sftp

I have this Python code , which creates a desktop screenshot (png) and save it locally, then  connect via sftp to a remote server and updload the screenshot file remotely.
using sftp . It works perfectly , however if the remote sftp server goes off
the scripts ends with an error . How to ignore and skip the error if the remote server sftp goes off
, I want to avoid the script to stop and instead save file locally.

```
import mss
import mss.tools
import datetime
import time
import pysftp as sftp


count = 0
while count < 100000000:
    with mss.mss() as sct:
        monitor = sct.monitors[1]
        timestr = time.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")
        sct.compression_level = -1
        output = "d:/screen/work/" + (timestr) + ".png".format(**monitor)
        sct_img = sct.grab(monitor)
        mss.tools.to_png(sct_img.rgb, sct_img.size, output=output)
        print(output)   
        s = sftp.Connection(host='127.0.0.1', username='admin', password='********')
        local_path = "" +(output)+ ""
        remote_path = ""
        s.put(local_path, remote_path)
        s.close()


    time.sleep(10)
    count += 1
```

I tried this

```
import mss
import mss.tools
import datetime
import time
import pysftp as sftp


count = 0
while count < 100000000:
    with mss.mss() as sct:
        monitor = sct.monitors[1]
        timestr = time.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")
        sct.compression_level = -1
        output = "d:/screen/work/" + (timestr) + ".png".format(**monitor)
        sct_img = sct.grab(monitor)
        mss.tools.to_png(sct_img.rgb, sct_img.size, output=output)
        print(output)  
        try:
    s = sftp.Connection(host='127.0.0.1', username='admin', password='********')
 except:
    print("Couldn't connect to ftp")
    return False 
        local_path = "" +(output)+ ""
        remote_path = ""
        s.put(local_path, remote_path)
        s.close()


    time.sleep(10)
    count += 1
```

but it returns this error

```
  s = sftp.Connection(host='127.0.0.1', username='admin', password='******')
    ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

Comment: Wrap the connection in a `try ... except` block and handle the error there

Comment: I tried it but I fall in IndentationError: expected an indented block , could you help me more showing the code (I do not know Python, only something) ?

Comment: [Why does Python use indentation for grouping of statements?](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/design.html#why-does-python-use-indentation-for-grouping-of-statements); [8. Compound statements](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html). You might like [the Official Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `try....except` block to catch all exceptions like this:

```py
import mss
import mss.tools
import datetime
import time
import pysftp as sftp


count = 0
while count < 100000000:
    with mss.mss() as sct:
        monitor = sct.monitors[1]
        timestr = time.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")
        sct.compression_level = -1
        output = "d:/screen/work/" + (timestr) + ".png".format(**monitor)
        sct_img = sct.grab(monitor)
        mss.tools.to_png(sct_img.rgb, sct_img.size, output=output)

        print(output)

        try:
            s = sftp.Connection(host="127.0.0.1", username="admin", password="********")
            local_path = "" + (output) + ""
            remote_path = ""
            s.put(local_path, remote_path)
            s.close()

        except:
            print("Couldn't connect to ftp")

        return False

    time.sleep(10)
    count += 1
```

However, it is not recommended to catch all exceptions blindly. You should inspect what exceptions are getting raised when there are errors and use them specifically like this:

```py
try:
    "...your code block that might raise en error..."
except ZeroDivisionError:
    print("Zero division error occurred")

except ValueError:
    print("Value error occured")
```

However, if you can't predict what error might pop up and have to catch exceptions somewhat blindly, then at least do `logging`. You can see more information regarding catching and logging exceptions [here.](https://github.com/rednafi/pysanity/blob/master/docs/guidelines.md#logging)

Comment: I receive "line 27
    except Exception:
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax"

Comment: Did you try the first example that I gave (putting everything inside the try...except block)? The code snippet is 25 lines long. Since your interpreter is showing error in line 27, that syntax error might be popping up from somewhere else.

Comment: Updated the answer according to your updates. Try this time.

Comment: I am using exactly the code above https://gist.github.com/graz68a/39a0411a2bdedcd2c971d7c0ece82204 , again errors    File "d:/screen/screen.py", line 30
    return False
    ^
SyntaxError: 'return' outside function

Answer (score 2):

Wrapping your connection inside a `try ... except` block like so will allow you to handle the error without terminating the program in the process:

```
# first part of your code here
try:
    s = sftp.Connection(host='127.0.0.1', username='admin', password='********')
    local_path = "" +(output)+ ""
    remote_path = ""
    s.put(local_path, remote_path)
    s.close()
except Exception as e:
    # do something with e here, e.g. print a log statement
    # your code for saving a local copy goes here as well
# rest of your code goes here
```

Note that you should replace my generic `Exception` by the connection error you're getting in order not to ignore anything else that might go wrong while connecting and transferring data as other errors probably cannot be ignored as easily

Comment: now it returns this with ftp running :      except Exception as e
                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax  . If there is no ftp connection I want simply skip the sftp job.

Comment: Can you share your code? This structure works for me

Comment: https://gist.github.com/graz68a/0497b0a866406892f3dd4449d9d25ef0

Comment: please ignore file above  https://gist.github.com/graz68a/2d2aa33fd90016ce176d86a85a6c0463

Comment: The except needs to be indented one level less and you need to define some statement inside that block as well. For now, you can just put `pass`